# lang not working on RMarkdown, the language doesn't change no matter the input

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, pandoc

I have a project for which the YAML output looks like this:

```yaml
---
lang: es-MX
title: "Example"
author: "Salvador BG"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: bookdown::html_document2
---
```

Then I have some tables, the only issue is that no matter the `lang` option I use, the tables still show "Table" instead of, say, "Tabla".

So far I haven't been able to find and answer, since most searches regarding Pandoc, YAML and Markdown show results regarding programming languages, and the ones that did had the same issue, were either not solved or have the issue solved by using `lang: es`, which does not change anything for me.

Using `lang: "es-MX"` doesn't solve it either, and doesn't look to be correct according to Pandoc `lang` documentation. Neither using

```yaml
header-includes:
    - \usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
```

Changing the `_bookdown.yml` file is also not an option since I have to write this kinds of projects both in Spanish and in English, so I'd have to be changing it often.

Take this example for instance:

````
---
lang: es-MX
title: "Example"
author: "Salvador BG"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

```{r}
example<-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
examplenames<-c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5")
for_table<-rbind(examplenames,example)
```

```{r forTable, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Example to show issue"}
kable(for_table, format = "html", align = "c", caption = "Example to show issue")  %>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 12, html_font = "Cambria", bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover")) %>%
  kable_classic_2(full_width = F)
```
````

After Kniting it, the table should have "Tabla 1: Example to show the issue", instead, it shows "Table 1: Example to show the issue".

Answer (score 0):

You must clear knit cache and then copy this `_bookdown.yaml` to your project folder.

```
book_filename: 'bookdown-demo'
language:
  label:
    fig: 'Figura '
    tab: 'Tabla '
    eq: 'Ecuación '
    thm: 'Teorema '
    lem: 'Lema '
    def: 'Definición '
    cor: 'Corolario '
    prp: 'Proposición '
    exm: 'Ejemplo '
    exr: 'Ejercicio '
    proof: 'Demostración '
    remark: 'Nota '
    solution: 'Solución '
    refs: 'Referencias '
  ui:
    chapter_name: 'CAPITULO '
delete_merged_file: true
```

As you can imagine this file changes not only 'table' for 'Tabla' but also for all the included tags.